# What is a call-spread and its formula?

Tags: programming, finance, quantitative, spread, call

I am attempting [Mark Joshi's The Concepts and Practice of Mathematical Finance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521514088).

In B.3 Project 1: Vanilla options in a Black-Scholes world, he asked the following question.

> We need to be sure that the formulas have been implemented correctly so run the following consistency checks.
>   The price of a call-spread should approximate the price of a digital-call option

What is a call-spread and its formula?

Comment: A Call Spread= long a Call with strike $K_1$ and short a call with strike $K_2$ both with the same maturity $T$. When $K_2$ is close to but slightly greater than $K_1$ this is equivalent to a Digital Call with strike $(K_1+K_2)/2$.

Comment: @noob2 So call spread requires both long and short?

Comment: Yes, it is just a portfolio of two calls, one long and one short. For both calls the formula is the usual Black Scholes formula. Then you take $C_1-C_2$.